# Optimization Algorithms for $ {L}_{0} $ Pseudo Norm Regularization

Tags: optimization, normed-spaces, convex-optimization, non-convex-optimization

I have a non-convex objective function with L0 constraint. I am struggling to find an approximate method to solve the problem. I would really grateful if someone could give a pointer to an algorithm.

Comment: By $\ell_0$ constraint do you mean that you have an $\ell_0$-penalty term in the objective function?

Comment: Yes, $\mathit{l}_{0}$-penalty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paper "[Low Rank Priors for Color Image Regularization](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=11008794778569932954&hl=en&as_sdt=0,43)" by Mollenhoff, Strekalovskiy, Moller, and Cremers contains a proximal algorithm that is useful for non-convex optimization and shows some examples where the $\ell_0$-penalty is used.